# How to change android:layout_alignParentRight runtime by java code

Tags: android, android-layout

I have chat list view in which sender name should be left aligned and receiver's reply should be on right side, and then vice a versa when receiver becomes sender.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/chatmessagename"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="16sp" android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/chatmessagedate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
    android:autoLink="none" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/chatmessagetext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/chatmessagename"
    android:autoLink="all" />
```

**Now at runtime i want to change textview's layout_alignParentRight value. Is it possible to do ?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
... 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)yourView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_.....); //ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT / LEFT etc.
yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
...
```

Comment: Thanks appserv, that does a trick for me.. after applying Align_parent, it wasn't working on one textview,  due to layout_width = "fill_parent" after converting it to 'wrap_content' it works... just a commonsense to use here :)

Answer (score 1):

yes is possible you can use this things:-

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                    textviewid);
```

form this code you get some ref..

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        _params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        apps_layout.setLayoutParams(_params);
```